# How to round Quantitys using Java's new Units of Measurement API?

Tags: java, rounding, units-of-measurement

How do I round `javax.measure.Quantity`s? There's got to be a way but I can't seem to find it.

If I've got `1.242742384474667939234868368726636 mph`, how do I get to `1.2 mph`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getValue() method to get the value.
Round the value, and then create a new Quantity with the rounded value and the original units

Comment: That would certainly work, but they wouldn't really create this nice api and then force us to jump through those hoops, would they?

Comment: Yes, they would. As nice as the api is, it deals mainly with making sure that units can only be combined / converted if they are compatible (e.g. km and mi, since both are distance units). The are only a few methods for manipulating the value, including add, subtract, multiply, and divide. There is no "round" method.